# Summing by groups of rows in R

Tags: r, matrix, sum, apply

This is a bit of a difficult question to title, so edits welcome.  The data looks like this:

```
mat =         

     [,1]
 [1,] 9.586352e-04
 [2,]           NA
 [3,] 2.605841e-03
 [4,] 7.868957e-05
 [5,] 1.000000e+00
 [6,]           NA
 [7,] 8.208500e-02
 [8,] 2.605841e-03
 [9,] 7.868957e-05
[10,] 1.000000e+00
[11,] 9.586352e-04
[12,] 8.208500e-02
[13,] 2.605841e-03
[14,] 7.868957e-05
[15,] 1.000000e+00
```

I want to sum every 5 elements, so since there are 15, I the length of the returned vector should be 3. (15/3).  So for example, just count the NA's as 0.

How do I do this?

I also want to ignore the NA's

Comment: could you please post code to fill mat with values? is `mat` a matrix?

Comment: "Error in vapply(split(EXPnumerator, rep(1:3, each = 5)), sum, 1L) : 
  values must be type 'integer',
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is type 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
In split.default(EXPnumerator, rep(1:3, each = 5)) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable"

Comment: 1           2           3 
0.007817522 0.000000000 0.000000000 
Warning message:
In split.default(mat, rep(1:3, each = 5)) :
  data length is not a multiple of split variable

Comment: Sorry my bad, it worked, but the first two return NA's.

Comment: 1      2      3 
    NA     NA 1.085728

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ideal for `?rowsum`, which should be fast

Using RStudent's data

```
rowsum(m, rep(1:3, each=5), na.rm=TRUE)
```

The second argument, `group`, defines the rows which to apply the sum over. More generally, the group argument could be defined `rep(1:nrow(m), each=5, length=nrow(m))` (sub `nrow` with `length` if applying over a vector)

Answer (score 6):

```
m <- matrix(1:15, ncol = 1)
m[cbind(c(3,7),c(1, 1))] <- NA

library(zoo)
rollapply(m, sum, width = 5, by = 5, na.rm = TRUE)
     [,1]
[1,]   12
[2,]   33
[3,]   65
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `tapply()`

```
mat <- matrix(c(1, 2, NA, 4:6, NA, 8:15))
## set up a grouping vector
grp <- rep(1:(nrow(mat)/5), each = 5)
## compute group sums
tapply(mat, grp, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
#  1  2  3 
# 12 33 65
```

A less efficient option involves `split()` with `vapply()`

```
vapply(split(mat, grp), sum, 1, na.rm = TRUE)
#  1  2  3 
# 12 33 65
```

Comment: Would it be better to use `rep(1:(nrow(mat)/5), each=5)` instead of `rep(1:3, each = 5)` ?

Comment: Yes, that would generalize it a bit better

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mat <- matrix(c(1, 2, NA, 4:6, NA, 8:15))
df <- data.frame(mat)

df %>%
  mutate(group = rep(1:(n()/5), each=5)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(mat = sum(mat, na.rm = TRUE))
```

You get:

```
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

#  group mat
#1     1  12
#2     2  33
#3     3  65
```

If, for some reasons, you would like to replace `NA`s by 0 (because you want to perform some other operations than a `sum()`, say a `mean()`) you can do:

```
df %>%
  mutate(mat = ifelse(is.na(mat), 0, mat)) %>%
  mutate(group = rep(1:(n()/5), each=5)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(mat = mean(mat))
```

You'll get the result with `NA`s equal to 0 (instead of omitting `NA` with `na.rm = TRUE` in previous suggestion)

```
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

#  group  mat
#1     1  2.4
#2     2  6.6
#3     3 13.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sum` function has an na.rm option.

```
dfsum <- numeric()
i <- 1
j <- 1
while (i < nrow(df)) { 
    dfsum[j] <- sum(df[i,2] : df [i+4,2], na.rm=TRUE)
    i <- i+5
    j <- j+ 1
}
```